# File Addition and Synchronization issues in RavenFS

Tags: ravendb, ravenfs

I am having a very hard time making RavenFS behave properly and was hoping that I could get some help.

I'm running into two separate issues, one where uploading files to the ravenfs while using an embedded db inside a service causes ravendb to fall over, and the other where synchronizing two instances setup in the same way makes the destination server fall over.

I have tried to do my best in documenting this... Code and steps to reproduce these issues are located here (https://github.com/punkcoder/RavenFSFileUploadAndSyncIssue), and video is located here (https://youtu.be/fZEvJo_UVpc). I tried looking for these issues in the issue tracker and didn't find something directly that looked like it related, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for this problem was to remove Raven from the project and replace it with MongoDB.  Binary storage in Mongo can be done on the record without issue.